# How to suppress the scientific notation when pandas.read_csv()?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, scientific-notation

I want to convert .csv file to dataframe in Python.
This is the codes.

```
import pandas as pd
csv_path = "./table.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(csv_path, error_bad_lines=False)
```

Below is original form of the .csv file when I opened it using Microsoft's notepad program.

**"019E0001"**

```
1    -   019E0001              -  ...            -           -   33312
2    -   019E0002              -  ...            -           -   43211
3    -   019E0003              -  ...            -           -   51588
```

But, when I read this .csv file in Python by using the function pandas.read_csv(), the value was converted to exponential form.
**"1.90E+02"**

```
1    -   1.90E+02              -  ...            -           -   33312
2    -   1.90E+03              -  ...            -           -   43211
3    -   1.90E+04              -  ...            -           -   51588
```

I don't want that change.

I want to reserve the original text form (019E0001)

How could I deal with this problem??

Help me

Answer (score 4):

Don't let Pandas infer datatype, so try to append `dtype=str` as argument of `read_csv` function:

```
import pandas as pd
csv_path = "./table.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(csv_path, error_bad_lines=False, dtype=str)  # <- HERE
```

After that, you can convert your other columns with the right dtype with `df.astype({'colX': float, ...})`

Comment: Can you convert to wiki, becuse dupe?