# How do I convert values that are given in scientific notation into decimals?

Tags: function, decimal, notation

How do I convert values that are given in scientific notation into decimals? This would be values in certain columns in a dataframe in a jupyter notebook.

I tried using the float function and the round function. I defined a function that search for the scientific notation values and converts them to float or decimals using the float function and the round function, however, the functions returned values that remained in scietific notation.

Comment: Showing what you are dealing with clearly would help here, otherwise I suggest multiplying by 1000 or 1000000 etc

Comment: See also ['Pandas read scientific notation and change'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34013790/8508004), ['How to suppress the scientific notation when pandas.read_csv()? duplicate'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69880314/8508004),  ['How to read a csv in scientic notation with capital E in Python?'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50598524/8508004), ['pd.read_csv converts the number to scientific notation'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70954684/8508004), ['How to Suppress Scientific Notation in Pandas'](https://saturncloud.io/blog/how-to-suppress-scientific-notation-in-pandas/), etc.